# If $x\mapsto F(x)=\int^{x}_{a}f(s)ds$, then $F$ is $C^1$ and $F'(x)=f(x),\;\;\forall\;x\in[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Assuming that \begin{align}f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}^n\end{align}
is continuous, and 
\begin{align}F:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}^n\end{align}
\begin{align}x\mapsto F(x)=\int^{x}_{a}f(s)ds.\end{align}
I want to prove that $F$ is $C^1$ and $F'(x)=f(x),\;\;\forall\;x\in[a,b].$

**MY WORK**

To prove differentiablity, it suffices to prove that \begin{align}\Vert F(x_0+h)- F(x_0)-hf(x_0)\Vert \leq\Vert h \Vert\epsilon(h)\end{align}

Since, $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}^n$, then it is uniformly continuous.

\begin{align}\Vert F(x_0+h)- F(x_0)-hf(x_0) \Vert\end{align}
\begin{align}=\Vert \int^{x_0+h}_{a}f(s)ds- \int^{x_0}_{a}f(s)ds-hf(x_0) \Vert\end{align}
\begin{align}=\Vert \int^{x_0+h}_{x_0}f(s)ds-hf(x_0) \Vert\end{align}
I'm stuck at this point, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Mean value theorem for integrals...

Comment: @amsmath Doesn't [the Mean value theorem fail for vector-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_integration_fails_for_vector-valued_functions)?

Comment: @Sobi Sure it does. I did not read carefully enough. My bad.

Comment: @amsmath Happened to me a million times! :)

Comment: @Sobi That happens because we wanna be the first to help, right? ;-)

Comment: @amsmath Exactly! To be completely honest with you, I had already started typing an answer that uses the Mean value theorem, and I almost posted it, but then I checked the question again and saw $\mathbb{R}^n$... :')

Comment: @Sobi I respect your honesty! Thumbs up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use that the integral over a constant is the constant times the interval length, in reverse
\begin{align}
\left\Vert \int^{x_0+h}_{x_0}f(s)\,ds-hf(x_0) \right\Vert
&=\left\Vert \int^{x_0+h}_{x_0}(f(s)-f(x_0))\,ds \right\Vert\\
&\le \int^{x_0+h}_{x_0}\Vert f(s)-f(x_0) \Vert\,ds
\end{align}

Comment: Wow, I love this!

Comment: Now, use uniform continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @amsmath: Done!